# Calculate a field using text from another field separated with comma

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, field-calculator, fields-attributes, select-by-attribute

I have an address field containing the following text: **"64,ramkoti,hyderabad,500070"**

I need to copy hyderabad to another field.

What would be the code used in the field calculator tool to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Use python parser and split:

```
def splitit(somefield):
    return somefield.split(',')[2] #2 is index for third word
```

Call with:

```
splitit(!yourfieldnamehere!)
```